# UITableView copy-delete-edit cells

Tags: ios4, uitableview

I am trying to implement a few functions on a UITableView, in order to give the users the ability to copy-delete-edit the cells.
I have read quite a lot about the UITableViewDelegate protocol and browsed the net; as well as done a lot of experimenting with the following methods.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
```

At this point I am still not getting what I want. More precisely, the "copy" part is working but the rest is not or not properly in all cases.

I have found quite precise information for the "copy". But for the "delete" it is much harder, and for the "edit" it is even harder.
I did not think delete-edit were so rare features, but whatever the reason here I am, fighting to solve my problem.

Has anyone ever tried to implement what I am working on now? Thanks for any piece of relevant information.

Comment: Have you found resolution for "delete" problem without implementing "delete:" selector in cell?